# Outlook Calendar Printing Assistant For Outlook 2013

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013

Has anyone had success installing the calendar printing assistant for Outlook 2013?  The download page http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16645 indicates that it should work for Office 2013 (32-bit).  I am attempting to install it on a machine that is running Windows 7 Pro (32-bit).  The install of Office is 2013 Home and Business.  It is not Office 365.  I read somewhere that people recommended compatibility mode for Win 7 if using Win 8.  This doesn't apply to me.  The following is the error message I recieve:

[image]

Can I install this with my current configuration?
Has anyone successfully made this work for them using Win 7 and Office 2013?
Was there anything special needed to make this work?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you put it in as text? I can't see it as I am in an environment in which Imgur is blocked. (Press Ctrl+C to copy the contents of the dialog)

Comment: "Setup cannot complete.  Calendar Printing Assistant for Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 requires the 2007 Microsoft Office system to be installed.  Please install the 2007 Microsoft Office system and then rerun setup."  However there are not multiple downloads on the download page, one download for all versions of Office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install Calendar Printing Assistant for Outlook 2013 you need to install an Office 2007 or 2010 product first.
I installed the [PowerPoint Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13) and then I was able to install the Calendar Printing Assistant. This is on a Windows 8 64-bit machine with Office 2013 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.  Microsoft has a fix for running this with Office 2013 without having to install any other product.  There is a registry fix.  Here is a link to the Microsoft Support Page.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2898576

Hope that helps.

Comment: It is preferred that you not link to the answer elsewhere, but include the necessary steps within your post.